# Ayuda a la hora de borrar un registro con ajax y php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Tengo un ***CRUD*** pero en vez de usuarios son preguntas gestionado todo con *Ajax*.

El tema es que el update create funcionan pero en delete que es exactamente igual que los demas no.

Paso a colgaros en código:

```
$('#deleteUser').click(function() {
if($('.checkBox:checked').val() == undefined){
    if(!$('#message').hasClass("alert alert-danger")) {
        $('#message').addClass("alert alert-danger").append("<a class='close'>×</a> <p>Tienes que seleccionar alguna pregunta</p>");
    }
    $('.close').click(function(){
        clearMessage();
    });
}else{
    $('#message').removeClass("alert alert-danger").empty();
    if(confirm("Estas seguro de que quieres eliminar la pregunta?")){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data:{
                funcion: 'deleteQuestion',
                Id: $('.checkBox:checked').val(),
            },
            url: '../php/questionsAdmin.php',
            success: function(data){
                if(data == 1){
                    loadQuestions();
                    addDoneButton("Pregunta eliminada correctamente");
                    $('.close').click(function(){
                        clearMessage();
                    });

                }else{
                    alert("algo no ha ido bien");
                }

            }

        })

    }
  }
});
```

El *delete* pregunta necesita que la pregunta tenga el `checkbox` activado, el primer `if` comprueba que este alguna pregunta selecciona y despues comprueba que no hay haya un mensaje de error en el `div`. Despues hace la llamada a ajax pasandole el id del `checkbox` (que es el id de la pregunta previamente cargado con ajax), si el success de la llamada es *true* mensaje de que todo ha ido bien sino un `alert`. 
Ahí va el codigo php:

```
function deleteQuestion($mysqli,$id){
$select = "DELETE FROM question WHERE Id = :id";
$row = $mysqli->prepare($select);
$row->execute(array(":id" => $id));

if($row->rowCount() == 1){
    echo 1;
}else{
    echo 0;
  }
}
```

`$mysqli` es la variable del archivo connect (que es el que conecta con la base de datos use *PDO*), lo he comprobado si era eso que estaba mal y esta bien la conexión, he probado la query que hace esta funcion manualmente en  mysql y si que funciona, también he mirado que la variable `$id` este bien recogida y si que la recoge bien, otras aclaraciones es que los campos y tabla también esta bien están bien puestos.

Comment: Supongo que tienes la función `deleteQuestion($mysqli,$id)` en el archivo  `questionsAdmin.php`. ¿Puedes mostrar, en dicho archivo PHP cómo haces para ejecutar la función de borrado. Algo como : `if (isset($_POST["deleteQuestion"])) { deleteQuestion($mysqli,$id);...}` Por otra parte, ¿si usas PDO por qué llamas a tu variable `$mysqli`... ? no pasa nada, puedes llamarle como quieras, pero es bueno ser coherentes en nuestro código. PDO y MySQLi no es lo mismo.

Comment: Deberias aclarar si utilizas PDO o mysqli, ya que el método <code>execute()</code> entre uno y otro varia, se entiende que es PDO y todo aparenta estar correcto y lo unico que se me ocurre es que el usuario de con el que te conectas no tenga privilegios. Puedes utilizar **print_r($row->errorInfo());** para mostrar los errores que devuelve mysql.

Comment: Utilizo PDO ya lo pude solicionar... el problema venia que no podia hacer el drop porque la tabla de preguntas estaba en "ON DELETE RESTRICT" y como tenía una clave foranea no me dejaba!